# Comparing two dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, difference

I've got two dataframes that both contain numbers. They both have the same size 10x350 (ten columns and 350 rows) I want to compare them and "do some logic"

Here are little extracts as an illustration:

```
Dataframe 1:               Dataframe 2:
A      B     C             A      B     C
47.7   20.2  12.1          90.7   73.8  216.7
47.2   20    11.9          114.9  68    155.6
46.4   19.6  11.7          110.8  67.8  160.3
```

I want to compare the dataframes and if the value from Dataframe 2 is higher store the difference.
(in this example all values from dataframe 2 are higher)
In the end all differences from the columns should be added up

In this case the sum of the differences are:

```
Sum_A = 175.1
Sum_B = 149.8
Sum_C = 496.9
```

I think using:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
```

might be possible. But I couldn't get the comparison of both dataframes to work

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried iterating through the dataframes. But I only got it to iterate through one dataframe at a time and not both

Comment: "if the value from Dataframe 2 is higher store the difference." --> what to store it it is not higher?

Comment: then reduce the Sum by that difference. Minimum should be zero

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df2.sub(df1).clip(lower=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
A    175.1
B    149.8
C    496.9
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def VerifyTable(context,actual_table, expected_table):
            n = []
            for actual_tablecolumns in actual_table.columns:
                n.append(actual_tablecolumns)
            print (n)
            m = []
            for expected_tablecolumns in expected_table.columns:
                m.append(expected_tablecolumns)
            print (m)
            if n == m:
                for actual_tablevalues in actual_table.values:
                    nn.append(actual_tablevalues)
                print (nn)
                mm = []
                for expected_tablevalues in expected_table.values:
                    mm.append(expected_tablevalues)
                if nn == mm:
                    return True

            return False
```

another code

```
def VerifyTable(context, actual_table, expected_table):
    #print("row count in actual table: " + str(len(actual_table.values)))
    currentRowIndex = -1
    currentColIndex = -1
    for row in actual_table.values:
        currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1
        currentColIndex = -1 #reset column index
        for cell_by_column in row:
            currentColIndex = currentColIndex + 1
            assert cell_by_column == expected_table.values[currentRowIndex][currentColIndex], "Mismatch of corresponding cells comparing actual and expected: " + cell_by_column + " != " + expected_table.values[currentRowIndex][currentColIndex]
    #TODO: Write code to compare/verify column headers as well!
```